# cant convert String to *net.TCPlistener type

Tags: go

i want to put string in net.Listener but i got error :

```
./server.go:26:23: cannot use mainServer (type interface {}) as type string in argument to net.Listen: need type assertion
./server.go:27:28: cannot use gpServer (type interface {}) as type string in argument to net.Listen: need type assertion
```

its my code :

```
  viper.SetConfigFile("config.json")
  viper.AddConfigPath(".")
  viper.SetConfigName("config")
  viper.ReadInConfig()
  fmt.Printf("Using config: %s\n", viper.ConfigFileUsed())
  mainServer := viper.Get("mainServer.port")
  gpServer := viper.Get("gpServer.port")

  fmt.Println(mainServer,gpServer)



  fmt.Println("started main server")
  ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", mainServer)
  gp_conn, _ := net.Listen("tcp", gpServer)
```

its my config.json :

```
    "mainServer": {
        "host": "",
        "port": ":2323",
        "enabled": true
    },
    "gpServer": {
        "host": "",
        "port": ":3232",
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

can some one explain me how i can convert string to net.TCPListener Type ? 
tnx

Comment: It says right in the error: `need type assertion`. Also check the docs, because the package you're using probably has a convenience method to do this for you.

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#GetString

Comment: Tnx "mad Wombat" ... My problem has been resolved ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the method `viper.GetString` would work better than `viper.Get` based on the documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper

```
mainServer := viper.GetString("mainServer.port")
gpServer := viper.GetString("gpServer.port")
```

However, you could assert the type directly...
This is ill-advised, as it will result in a panic if the type is not a string.

```
ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", mainServer.(string))
gp_conn, _ := net.Listen("tcp", gpServer.(string))
```